# Converting from Milliseconds to DateTime

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I have used the code:

```
Dim val = ( _
        New DateTime( _
            DateTimePicker1.Value.Year, _
            DateTimePicker1.Value.Month, _
            DateTimePicker1.Value.Day, _
            CInt(TextBox1.Text), _
            CInt(TextBox2.Text), _
            0 _
        ) _
        - _
        New DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0) _
    ).TotalMilliseconds
val = val + (CInt(TextBox2.Text) * 1000)
```

to get the milliseconds from 01/01/1970 using the selected input date and time. Does anyone know how to convert this value back into something that I can use to display the date in a `DateTimePicker` along with the hours and minutes that I can use some-place else?

Comment: I am confused, you are creating a date object from the `DateTimePicker` values, then finding the difference between the date and January 1st, 1970 in milliseconds; only then to turn it back into a date again for display elsewhere? Why?

Comment: So you want to convert the nr. of milliseconds from `1970-01-01` to some date back into a `DateTime`?

Comment: But you have a date difference now, not date. Do you want to display year 43 for 2013 entered into the first date picker?

Comment: I have them display a string of values to the user, which includes that value. Then they can import this string at a later date and have it display the data, I just need a way to undo the millisecond conversion.

Comment: The value is used in JavaScript some-place else, where the lowest value for a date is 01/01/1970.

Comment: Curious: it looks like you're using TextBox2 as both Minutes and Seconds here. The constructor uses it in the Minutes position, but then you add it back later as if it were seconds.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn That's just for an approximation, since I don't have a textbox dedicated to seconds I just add them. I don't need it to be accurate.

Comment: Then why do anything with seconds at all? Why not leave it at zero?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `DateTime` object's `AddMilliseconds()` method, like this:

```
' Calculation of milleseconds
Dim val = (New DateTime(DateTimePicker1.Value.Year, DateTimePicker1.Value.Month, DateTimePicker1.Value.Day, CInt(TextBox1.Text), CInt(TextBox2.Text), 0) - New DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)).TotalMilliseconds

' Start with new date object as January 1st, 1970 and then add milliseconds calculated above
Dim dateJan1st1970 As New DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)
Dim dateNew As DateTime = dateJan1st1970.AddMilliseconds(val)
```

Comment: Or even just .AddSeconds(), since that's what he starts with

Comment: I thought TimeSpan was the class to use in duration calculations

Answer (score 3):

Wow, that is way over-complicated:

```
Dim epoch As New DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)

Dim val = (DateTimePicker1.Value.AddSeconds(CInt(TextBox2.Text)) - epoch).TotalMilliseconds
```

Comment: Hmm... missed the other textboxes. It's still easier to do it this way, though.